# How to pass an error from a function to a catch block

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote a simple route that performs the addition of two numbers.

```
import express from 'express';
import { isNumber } from 'util';

const router = express.Router();

// handles url http://localhost:8082/api/sum
router.get('/sum', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const a = req.query.a; // 1
        const b = req.query.b; // g
        const result = await checkForNumber(a, b);
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Sum',
            sum: result,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            Error,
        });
    };
});

function checkForNumber(a, b) {
    if (isNumber(a) || isNumber(b)) {
        return a + b;
    }
    return new Error('NAN');
};
```

How can I get an error from a function in a catch block?

Because now I get an empty object.

```
{
    "message": "Sum",
    "sum": {}
}
```

And I need to get into the catch block and send the user an error if the variable is not a number.

```
{
    "Error": "NAN"
}
```

I read about errors in the library documentation [express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) but how to pass an error from a function I cannot understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `throw new Error('NAN');` instead of `return new Error('NAN');`

Also, the error handler should look like this instead:

```js
return res.status(422).json({
  Error: err.message
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the

```
{
    "message": "Sum",
    "sum": {}
}
```

because the try/catch block is executing properly, the try executes so it doesn't get to the catch. Because of that, the block

```
return res.status(422).json({
            Error,
        });
```

is never executing since there's no errors in the block.
The problem resides at the `const result = await checkForNumber(a, b);`, what I would do is the following:

```
try {
        const a = req.query.a; // 1
        const b = req.query.b; // g
        const result = await checkForNumber(a, b);
        let resultType = typeof result;
        if(resultType == "object") { //Check here if the const result is the error object or an integer and act consequently
          return res.status(422).json({
            Error,
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Sum',
            sum: result,
        });
        }

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            Error,
        });
    };
```

Btw if when you're creating the `new Error('NAN');` and the output is `{}` instead of `"NAN"`, there's probably something wrong at the Error class too.

Answer (score 1):

Just put condition like this

```
if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
  throw new Error("NAN");
}
```

before

`const result = await checkForNumber(a, b);`

do something like this :

```
catch (err) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            'error' : err.message || err
        });
    }
```

Comment: I do not check the variable for `NAN`, I check the variables for whether they are a number, if they are not an error that one of the values is not a number

Comment: OK then 
do it like this
instead of using `return new Error('NAN');` use `throw new Error('NAN');`

Comment: One more thing

instead of `return res.status(422).json({
            Error,
        });`

do it like

`return res.status(422).json({
            'error' : err.message || err
        });`

Udated my answer